# How to configure Maven-exec plugin with java classpath

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

i am trying to run the maven-exec plugin with referring the jar file as classpath like this

```
<configuration>
  <executable>java</executable>
  <longClasspath>true</longClasspath>
  <commandlineArgs>-classpath jarfile; Sample
  </commandlineArgs>
</configuration>
```

but my classpath is not set properly thus thrown an classNotFoundException. How to configure this?

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, for example is the jarfile the result of your build or an independent file? Do you need to run this file in a separate jvm or could it run inside the mvn process?

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath shouldn't end with a semicolon. Just `-classpath jarfile Sample`, assuming that "Sample" is the name of the class you're trying to run. I'd also eliminate the newline at the end of that command line string to be safe.